# Menu transition effect using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want this menu to be open and closed smoothly using JS animate.

[JS Based Menu](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)  any body can help me in this small issue ?

Comment: Do you want to add animation for collapse and expansion of the menu?

Comment: Yes ! your right. currently you can see its simple.

Answer (score 0):

$("any").toggle();

Just need to pass value in  $("p").toggle(500); e.g 500 and there will be animation.